# in java I am confused on when to make a class public

Tags: java

I am going through head into java and came across this example

```
interface Nose{
    public int iMethod();
}

abstract class Picasso implements Nose{
    public int iMethod(){
        return 7;
    }
}

class Clowns extends Picasso{}

class Acts extends Picasso{
    public int iMethod(){
        return 5;
    }
}
```

Because nothing is declared public, doesn't that mean that none of these classes can be called from another file? I have another file

```
public class Of76 extends Clowns{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Nose [] i = new Nose[3];
        i[0] = new Acts();
        i[1] = new Clowns();
        i[2] = new Of76();
        for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            System.out.println(i[x].iMethod()+" "+i[x].getClass());
        }

    }
}
```

So in this example class Of76 can make classes out of another file that doesn't have any public classes. I am confused on why the first file can have all those classes and why they are not in separate classes. I read that a class that is not public is private by default, and can only be called within the same class. So everything in the Nose file can only be called inside that Nose file?

Comment: *class that is not public is private by default* - Where did you read that? That's plain wrong.

Comment: "a class that is not public is private by default" is NOT true in Java!...

Comment: Also a class cannot be declared `private` or `protected` unless it is an inner class or a static nested class.

Comment: I must have read wrong, I meant package private not private

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you exlude `public` and don't have anything else there like `protected` or `private` this is called "package protected".  This should explain the differences to you: [In Java, difference between default, public, protected, and private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private)

Comment: Thanks I think I understand more. When it says "in the same package" does that mean in the same folder? So in the example I showed, Of76 can make objects of Nose, because they are from the same folder/package. If it was public, I can access classes from any other folder? how would I specify what folder they are in.

Comment: @JacobHong no, it means in the same package, not necessarily the same folder.  For example, if you created two jars which both had the same package, these package protected classes could "see" each other, even though they're in different folders.  This is a very esoteric fact that you don't usually take advantage of.  But, one way of using this is to let test classes in a different folder call package protected methods on production classes.

Comment: ok thanks, I think I have enough to move on, I havent learned about jars yet or packages yet. I come from python and I assumed a package was a library or something you would import ( a folder of modules).

Comment: No, a package is more like a namespace.  A Jar is a way to distribute a library.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question is a matter of perspective.

If you are a new Java learner and you are learning language features and the object-oriented paradigm, then a reasonable answer is "you should always make classes `public`" because visibility restrictions matter to nobody but you.  Visibility is an issue only for production code or when you are exporting an API for other clients to use.  It is not unreasonable to make classes public until you know how to write good classes (I would **NOT** extend this advice to fields of classes, however).

However...

If you are maintaining or modifying production code -or- developing an API that you intend to export for other programmers to use, then the best answer is "you should never make classes `public` unless your clear intent is that your clients should be able to access your class and use it in their own client code.

Visibility is one of the most important security and encapsulation mechanisms in Java and you should never be cavalier about it in a production environment.  Everything in your API should have the lowest possible visibility.

There are some important exceptions that can be imposed upon you by other API's that you may be using.  For example, if you are developing a controller class for JavaFX, then in JavaFX 2.2 you are required to make your class public, whether you want to or not.  Even so, these exceptions do not break the rule that "everything in your API should have the lowest possible visibility."

TL;DR: If the code you're working on will be accessed only by you, then you need never make classes anything but public.  If you're working on production code, code that will become available to others, or an API that you intend to export for client use, then you should never make classes public unless it is a clearly indicated part of your design.

- `public MyClass` this class will be visible to classes in your package and classes in other packages.
- `protected MyClass` this class will be visible to classes in your package and only other classes that are subclasses of MyClass.
- `MyClass` this is "default access" or "package-private" access.  MyClass is visible only to classes in the same package.
- `private MyClass` this class is not visisble to other classes except those that are in the same .class file.

Default access and Private access are considered non-exported visibility levels.  Classes with these visibility levels may be freely modified by you as their implementation details are not exported as part of any API.

Public and protected access are considered exported visibility levels.  Generally, once you've exported a class as part of your API you are expected to continue to support it "forever".